# Display Application Source Code Files in MkDocs Code Block

Tags: version-control, mkdocs

How can I display existing source code files within MkDocs? I want to include the files directly from another GitHub repository in code blocks without reformatting them so updated files will be shown in the MkDocs document.

**sample_code.py**

```py
    def fn():
        pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#fenced-code-blocks) with [Snippets extension](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/). Snippets and/or off-line processing require files to be available locally which is explained in the Pro Git book [Git Tools Submodules section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules/).

1. Include full file path even if the file in the same folder:

**index.md**

````
.
```python
--8<-- "docs/sample_code.py"
```
.
````

2. Create the source code file:

**sample_code.py**

```
def fn():
    pass
```

3. Add the extension to mkdocs configuration file:

**mkdocs.yml**

```
site_name: Demo

markdown_extensions:
    - pymdownx.snippets:

nav:
    - Demo: index.md
```

---

**Output**

.

```
def fn():
    pass
```

.