# Are there ways to link mkdocs documentation directly to specific part of git repo?

Tags: mkdocs

It is great that mkdocs allows snippets and display of repo information, but I haven't found a way to create a "view source" link that could direct viewers directly to relevant part of a git repo remote. Are there ways to enable this?

A good example is pandas' "Source" link shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to embed external files in code snippets [[1](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/code-blocks/#embedding-external-files)] which is also highlighted in a StackOverflow post [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260855/)] but unfortunately as of this writing there is no way to link to source files in the repo.

There are a few GitHub issues that seem to ask about adding files from outside the `docs` folder but they are more about displaying those markdown files within MKDocs and not about including links to them. [[3](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1373)][[4](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/3061)]